# How to do two nested object aggregations in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Data preparation

```
    PUT multvalue/
    {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "group": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "type": "nested"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PUT multvalue/_doc/4
    {
      "group" : "fans",
      "user" : [ 
        {
          "first" : "John",
          "count" :  8
        },
        {
          "first" : "Alice",
          "count" :  9
        },
        {
          "first" : "Xia",
          "count" :  10
        }
      ]
    }

    PUT multvalue/_doc/6
    {
      "group" : "fans",
      "user" : [ 
        {
          "first" : "John",
          "count" :  8
        },
        {
          "first" : "Alice",
          "count" :  9
        },
        {
          "first" : "Xia",
          "count" :  10
        }
      ]
    }
```

Hope the result of data aggregation:
（Accumulate the count of the same feild）

```
    [{
      "first" : "John",
      "count" :  16
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "count" :  18
    },
    {
      "first" : "Xia",
      "count" :  20
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html). Try out this below query -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "user"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_user": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user.first.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_value": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "user.count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Alice",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "count_value": {
              "value": 18.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "John",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "count_value": {
              "value": 16.0
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Xia",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "count_value": {
              "value": 20.0
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: @coerstack did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @coerstack if the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 